# Explain this for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, infinite-loop

`int i; for ( i = 0; i = 3; i++ ) printf("Hello");`

In this C code, the loop condition is "i = 3". What does this condition mean? And the loop runs infintely. Does that mean the condition is true?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: And as any decent book, tutorial or class should have taught you, all values besides `0` are "true". Only zero is "false".

Comment: It's an infinite loop. Looks like a typo - the author probably meant `i == 3` or `i != 3`.

Comment: I wonder why you just didn't try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test part in your for loop is `i = 3` which is an assignment to the variable. After assignment it evaluates as the which has been assigned: `3` which is not `0` hence true in `C`.
Then the condition of your for loop is always hence you have an infinite loop.

If the condition was `i == 3`, it would be false at the first iteration of the loop. hence the code will never execute the body of the for block.

If the condition was `i < 3`, it would be true until the `i` variable is incremented up to the 3 value. Hence the body of the for loop would execute 3 times